# any reason to use an outbound policy in apim?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Is there any reason to use an outbound policy in APIM? I tried a test where I used the same policy expression for inbound as well as outbound.  The same expression worked without error and returned the same info for both.  I don't see any need to configure an outbound policy if an inbound expression already captures all of the information. Have you also found the outbound section to be redundant and simply excluded the outbound section?  Or have you found any reason to use the outbound section in addition to the inbound section?

Answer (score 2):

Outbound policies can be used to manipulate/inspect a response body or headers returned from a backend API.

Examples of things you might do in an outbound policy:

- Set the cache duration based on the Cache-Control header returned from the API
- Remove headers created by the API framework like X-Powered-By and X-Aspnet-Version
- Calculate an etag value using a checksum of the body
- Create a signature header to prevent tampering with a response body
- Update the returned response body with cached fragments
- Log the returned response to a diagnostic system or audit trail

Comment: The response body/header can also be inspected from the inbound policy.   I'm not familiar with the manipulation aspect you mentioned.  Can you please explain?

Comment: @GregBrattle Yes you can inspect/set response headers and body in the inbound policy, however if you do, there is the possibility that the backend will overwrite those changes.  If you update the response in the outbound you can ensure that your changes will not be overwritten.  Also, if you inspect the response body in the inbound policy you will be doing so before the backend has handled the request and produced its response.

Comment: The inbound policy returns context.Response.StatusCode = 200 on successful requests

Comment: @GregBrattle I would expect it to return 200 on every request because 200 is the default value when you create a new instance of HttpResponseMessage.

Comment: <inbound> also returns a descriptive response body when an invalid url is requested:

{Response.Body:{ "statusCode": 404,
"message": "Resource not found" }},{Response.Headers:{ Key = Content-Length, Val
ue = 54 },{ Key = Content-Type, Value = application/json }},{context.Response.St
atusCode:404},{context.Response.StatusReason:Resource Not Found}

Comment: @GregBrattle I will investigate, but I suspect the reason for that is because in APIM you define operations and therefore the APIM gateway can detect invalid URLs before the backend is ever called.  I am guessing that if you had an operation setup with a wildcard /* then you wouldn't see that 404 in the inbound.